# How can I control iTunes from another Mac?

Tags: macos, itunes, remote-control

I've got a Mac Mini running Lion that stores my iTunes library. It's hooked up to my receiver and speaker system, so it's the preferred machine for playing tunes from. I'd like to be able to control iTunes from my MacBook Pro, also running Lion, connected to the same WiFi network.

I can use Screen Sharing, but that's a tad resource-intensive to leave running all the time on my mid-2009 MBP. [iTunes Remote Control](http://them.ws/itrc/) does exactly what I am looking for, but - call me superficial if you like - it doesn't blend in on my desktop. I would ideally like something a little OSXier, or at least alternatively to use a utility with no interface at all - just keyboard shortcuts.

That's a lot to ask for, and iTunes Remote Control will probably be my best bet, but I am hoping somebody here has a perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been using [TuneConnect](http://www.tuneconnect.net/) to do pretty much what you're after. It's got, what I consider to be, a much nicer UI that iTunes Remote Control. You install a server component on your iTunes machine and the remote component on the machine you want to control iTunes from and it just...works.

I've been running it without any issues on Lion. It ran well for me on Snow Leopard as well.

[image: TuneConnect Remote UI]

[image: TuneConnect Server Config UI]

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: Looks like OS X.0...

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/p/tunesremote-se/

> TunesRemote SE helps you remote control your DACP-compatible media player from another computer running Java. DACP compatible media players include:
>
> - Apple iTunes (Tested working)
> - MonkeyTunes for MediaMonkey (Confirmed working)
> - AlbumPlayer
> - Telescope for Songbird
> - foo_touchremote for Foobar2000
> - RhythmBox for Gnome
>
> 'Digital Audio Control Protocol' (DACP) is a protocol used by the Apple Inc.'s Remote application (app) on the iPhone to control iTunes running on a remote computer. By implementing this protocol TunesRemote SE allows any desktop or laptop to be used as remote control for your media.
>
> TunesRemote SE combines the graphical user interface of Firefly Client with the DACP control software from TunesRemote+.